# "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 1. \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"

Tags: flutter-web

I have this code:

```
import 'dart:convert';        
import 'package:hr_jobform/customColors.dart';        
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;        
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';        
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';        

class CitiesStateDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {        
  const CitiesStateDropdownButton({super.key});        

  @override        
  State<CitiesStateDropdownButton> createState() =>        
      CitiesStateDropdownButtonState();        
}        

class CitiesStateDropdownButtonState        
    extends State<CitiesStateDropdownButton> {        

  @override        
  void initState() {        
    _getStatesList();        
    super.initState();        
  }        

  @override        
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {        
    return Wrap(children: <Widget>[        
      Padding(        
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 15, 8, 8),        
        child: ConstrainedBox(        
          constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(219, 50)),        
          child: DropdownButton<String>(        
            value: _state,        
            iconSize: 30,        
            icon: (null),        
            style: TextStyle(        
              color: Palette.customColors,        
              fontSize: 16,        
            ),        
            hint: Text('Select State'),        
            onChanged: (String? newValue) {        
              setState(() {        
                _state = newValue!;        
                _getCitiesList();        
                print(_state);        
              });        
            },        
            items: states?.map((item) {        
                  return new DropdownMenuItem(        
                    child: new Text(item['name']),        
                    value: item['id'].toString(),        
                  );        
                })?.toList() ??        
                [],        
          ),        
        ),        
      ),        
      //======================================================== City        
      Wrap(        
        children: <Widget>[        
          Padding(        
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 15, 8, 8),        
            child: ConstrainedBox(        
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(187, 50)),        
              child: DropdownButton<String>(        
                value: _city,        
                iconSize: 30,        
                icon: (null),        
                style: TextStyle(        
                  color: Palette.customColors,        
                  fontSize: 16,        
                ),        
                hint: Text('Select City'),        
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {        
                  setState(() {        
                    _city = newValue!;        
                    print(_city);        
                  });        
                },        
                items: cities?.map((item) {        
                      return new DropdownMenuItem(        
                        child: new Text(item['name']),        
                        value: item['id'].toString(),        
                      );        
                    })?.toList() ??        
                    [],        
              ),        
            ),        
          ),        
        ],        
      ),        
    ]);        
  }        

  //=============================================================================== Api Calling here        

//CALLING State API HERE        
// Get Departamento information by API        
  late List states = [];        
  late String _state = '1';        

  String statesUrl =        
      "http://localhost:3000/states/getAllStates";        

  _getStatesList() async {        
    try {        
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(statesUrl));        
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {        
        print(response.body);        
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);        
        setState(() {        
          states = data['state'];        
        });        
        return jsonDecode(response.body);        
      } else {        
        return ("Server Error");        
      }        
    } catch (e) {        
      return print(e);        
    }        
  }        

  // Get Cities information by API        
  late List cities = [];        
  late String _city = '1';        

  _getCitiesList() async {        
    try {        
      http.Response response = await         http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:3000/cities/getAllCities?id=$_state"));        
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {        
        print(response.body);        
        var data = jsonDecode(response.body);        
        setState(() {        
          cities = data['City'];        
          print(cities);        
        });        
        return jsonDecode(response.body);        
      } else {        
        return ("Server Error");        
      }        
    } catch (e) {        
      return print(e);        
    }        
  }        
}
```

It runs well, but when i select one of the States on my dropdown list, the cities api call is successful as it appears on console, but the cities dropdown gives me this error:

```
Assertion failed:        

items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||        
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {        
                return item.value == value;        
              }).length == 1        
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 1. \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"
```

Please I've been struggling with this error for a couple of days now, I would appreciate if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

While using with future items from dropDown, use nullable value for DropdownButton.

```dart
  String? _state;
  String? _city;
```

And set Value on successful response only, otherwise set `_city=null` and `_state = null`

```dart
  setState(() {
          final List<String> items = data['City'].toList().toSet(); // trying to get unique value set
          cities = items.toList();
          _city = cities.first;
          print(cities);
        });
```

Do the same for others

Comment: Thanks for the response Yeasin, I modified the code to the one you instructed above, but now it gives me this error: 
Expected a value of type 'List<String>', but got one of type '_HashSet<dynamic>'
And setState() never gets called. How do I solve this? or can you be more clear on how to modify my ode to add yours, in case I am the one making some mistake.

Comment: can you type cas `data['City'] as List`there

Comment: Now it says Expected a value of type 'List<String>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Comment: can you include the response , also try `data['City'] as List<String>`